# Question related to career change

Tags: support

Are questions like these on topic here ?

> My current work experience in this digital Marketing is 2 years, I am looking
>   for a career in programming. The digital Marketing is not related to programming
>   at all.  Will these 2 years negatively affect my new job opportunities for
>   programming ?

Comment: 'Questions asking for **advice on what to do are not [practical answerable questions](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)** (e.g. *"what job should I take?"*, or *"what skills should I learn?"*)...' ([close reasons](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695/168))

Comment: @gnat I did see that, but those questions like _What job should I take_ or _What skills should I learn_ are not so close to my question because I am not asking for recommendation for job, rather a situation in job career, which is primarily opinion based as I learnt more when I explored the Meta Workplace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking.

I'd think pretty obviously, if an employer wants to hire a programmer and they have a choice between someone with 2 years of programming experience and someone with 2 years experience as, say, an auto mechanic, the person with programming experience will have an advantage.

Would an employer looking to hire a programmer view someone who had worked 2 years as an auto mechanic less favorably than someone who had zero experience? I doubt it. If you did a good job as an auto mechanic, that at least proves something about your work habits. Did you show up on time, work well with others, play by the rules, etc?

Experience in an unrelated field is surely worth LESS than experience in the relevant field, but it's worth more than zero.

Unless you're experience is in a field that's very disreputable -- you were a drug dealer or a pornographer or a politician or something -- I can't imagine that an employer would view it as a minus.

Comment: I have edited my question. Can you please take a look and let me know.

Comment: Doesn't really change my answer. Yes, I could swap in "digital marketing" for "auto mechanics" and the last paragraph goes away, but besides that I think my answer stands.